# How to display an URL added by the user in Django template?

Tags: python, html, django

I have the following Dashboard and I have to add a section called `Design` where the users will be able to have an input file and add their own design link files.

Right now this don't work, they are just html tags. What I want to achieve is that the user add their Figma or Sketch link, click on the `Add Link` button and then the link displays below the input.

I added this to the model:

`design_file = models.URLField(max_length=250)`

and this is how my html file looks like:

```
<div class="project-details__section scrollbar scrollactivity">
    <h2 class="project-details__subhead">Design</h2>
    <input type="text">
    <button>Add Link</button>
</div>
```

Any suggestions in how to achieve this? I saw several tutorials but I can't connect what I need with the given information. I know this is very basic but I'm kind new with Django.

Here is an screenshot:

[image]

Comment: You can try javascript (which you probably don't want to), what you probably want is to relaoad the page passing the var with the url, and then having a way to display it if it is defined or not. (default opage will not have a value for that, once user clicks add link you load the same page passing that value as a var and render it

Comment: Read the [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/) on how to work with forms and also [how to create forms from models](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/). You need to create a `ModelForm` for your model and create a view that renders the form and processes it, just like in the tutorials.